# How can I look at my composer packages and see what is out of date?

Tags: composer-php

I am using Magento 2 and I run all of my updates through Composer. I would like to see what Composer packages I have that are currently out of date. When I run `composer outdated` I get this:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>     Command "outdated" is not defined.

Is there another command I can use?

Comment: What `composer -V` returns to you?

Comment: @rob006 Composer version @package_branch_alias_version@ (1.0.0-beta2) 2016-03-27 16:00:34

Comment: This question does not ask about software recommendation, it is about how to use software (Composer - dependency manager for PHP).

Comment: @rob006 the question is asking for a manual for Composer, which is an offsite resource. If they look at the manual or just `composer list` they will find (or not find) what they are looking for.

Comment: @miken32 The question is basically "Why `composer outdated` command does not work?`". You will not find answer to this in Composer's documentation, you will only find info that such command exist (which is does not explain why it does not work in this particular case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Composer *is* too old. `outdated` command was introduced in `1.1.0`. If you're using pretty ancient `1.0.0-beta2`, you may missing many features and bugfixes, you should really upgrade to the last version.

If `1.0.0-beta2` is the last version available in repository of your Linux distribution, you may try uninstalling it and download last version directly using instructions from [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/download/). Official repositories are often focused on stability and they're avoiding non-patch upgrades. In many cases it means that PHP packages from official repositories are pretty outdated (2 years is like ages in PHP world). You should either install such packages directly from source or use some alternative repositories with more fresh packages (like [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/composer) for Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have an old version of Composer, before the [`outdated`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#outdated) command has been introduced.

As its documentation says, `composer outdated` is just an alias of [`composer show -lo`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#show). The two options of `composer show` mean:

- `-l` (short of `--latest`): List all installed packages including their latest version.
- `-o` (short of `--outdated`): Implies `--latest`, but this lists only packages that have a newer version available.

Or you can run [`composer self-update`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#self-update-selfupdate-) to update Composer to its latest version then run [`composer outdated`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#outdated) again.

Comment: When I try and run composer show -lo I get this error-  [RuntimeException]               
  The "-l" option does not exist. When I run composer self-update I get this error- [InvalidArgumentException]             
  Command "self-update" is not defined.

Comment: `self-update` is also named `selfupdate`. How old is your Composer?

Comment: Shouldn't be that old, I just installed Linux on it in January. Selfupdate gave the same result.